# "R" and SQL to query large JSON data

Tags: r, json, dataframe, dplyr, geolocation

I have a large JSON file (383,255KB). It contains street names, addresses, and lat/long values.
I think I'm right in saying this is a WGS84 World Geodetic System 84 file format.

All I want to do is query this data, in "R".
I'm thinking in SQL, because it is efficient in this context, but
I am not aware of any package/method to take this approach.

I would like to:

```
  select Latitude, Longitude From JSONData Where Address = "160" and LFNAME = "Transit Rd"
```

The structure (and a few relevant data blocks) of the JSON data file are shown here:

```
{
    "type" : "FeatureCollection",
    "name" : "ADDRESS_POINT_WGS84",
    "features" : [
        {
            "type" : "Feature",
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [ -79.539538708, 43.586921565 ]
            },
            "properties" : {
                "GEO_ID" : 5729529,
                "LINK" : 5729516,
                "MAINT_STAG" : "REGULAR",
                "ADDRESS" : "399",
                "LFNAME" : "Lake Promenade",
                "LO_NUM" : 399,
                "LONUMSUF" : null,
                "HINUM" : null,
                "HINUMSUF" : null,
                "ARC_SIDE" : "L",
                "DISTANCE" : 4.15,
                "FCODE" : 115001,
                "FCODE_DES" : "Unknown",
                "CLASS" : "Land",
                "NAME" : null,
                "X" : 301607.151,
                "Y" : 4827443.931,
                "LONGITUDE" : -79.5395419864,
                "LATITUDE" : 43.5869301259,
                "OBJECTID" : 1491585,
                "MUN_NAME" : "Etobicoke",
                "WARD_NAME" : "Etobicoke-Lakeshore"
            }
        },
        {
            "type" : "Feature",
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [ -79.540371034, 43.5882630139 ]
            },
            "properties" : {
                "GEO_ID" : 9950585,
                "LINK" : 9950578,
                "MAINT_STAG" : "REGULAR",
                "ADDRESS" : "7",
                "LFNAME" : "Hilo Rd",
                "LO_NUM" : 7,
                "LONUMSUF" : null,
                "HINUM" : null,
                "HINUMSUF" : null,
                "ARC_SIDE" : "L",
                "DISTANCE" : 43.77,
                "FCODE" : 115001,
                "FCODE_DES" : "Unknown",
                "CLASS" : "Land",
                "NAME" : null,
                "X" : 301540.011,
                "Y" : 4827592.989,
                "LONGITUDE" : -79.5403743125,
                "LATITUDE" : 43.5882715763,
                "OBJECTID" : 1491586,
                "MUN_NAME" : "Etobicoke",
                "WARD_NAME" : "Etobicoke-Lakeshore"
            }
        },
        {
            "type" : "Feature",
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [ -79.5390269742, 43.587174988 ]
            },
            "properties" : {
                "GEO_ID" : 5729496,
                "LINK" : 5729468,
                "MAINT_STAG" : "REGULAR",
                "ADDRESS" : "387",
                "LFNAME" : "Lake Promenade",
                "LO_NUM" : 387,
                "LONUMSUF" : null,
                "HINUM" : null,
                "HINUMSUF" : null,
                "ARC_SIDE" : "L",
                "DISTANCE" : 97.58,
                "FCODE" : 115001,
                "FCODE_DES" : "Unknown",
                "CLASS" : "Land",
                "NAME" : null,
                "X" : 301648.488,
                "Y" : 4827472.065,
                "LONGITUDE" : -79.5390302568,
                "LATITUDE" : 43.5871835468,
                "OBJECTID" : 1491591,
                "MUN_NAME" : "Etobicoke",
                "WARD_NAME" : "Etobicoke-Lakeshore"
            }
        },
        {
            "type" : "Feature",
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [ -79.3880422943, 43.6830929049 ]
            },
            "properties" : {
                "GEO_ID" : 850466,
                "LINK" : 20002604,
                "MAINT_STAG" : "REGULAR",
                "ADDRESS" : "1",
                "LFNAME" : "Ottawa St",
                "LO_NUM" : 1,
                "LONUMSUF" : null,
                "HINUM" : null,
                "HINUMSUF" : null,
                "ARC_SIDE" : "R",
                "DISTANCE" : 3.99,
                "FCODE" : 115001,
                "FCODE_DES" : "Unknown",
                "CLASS" : "Land",
                "NAME" : null,
                "X" : 313826.457,
                "Y" : 4838133.322,
                "LONGITUDE" : -79.388042294,
                "LATITUDE" : 43.683092902,
                "OBJECTID" : 4675851,
                "MUN_NAME" : "former Toronto",
                "WARD_NAME" : "University-Rosedale"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I will be looking up lat/long values for thousands of city addresses, so it makes sense to have the data in memory.

I ***haven't*** completely read this article: https://themockup.blog/posts/2020-05-22-parsing-json-in-r-with-jsonlite/

I've read about "Rectangling" here: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/rectangle.html.
I monkeyed about, it seems too complicated to me.

I must be going about this the wrong way, and I honestly don't know what approach to take.
I'm just determining lat/long values for addresses.
Once I have the lat/long values for the "items" I'm tracking, I will show those items on a map.

Isn't there another better way?

Thank you for any tips/advice/pointers.

Richard

Comment: what you have is [geojson](https://geojson.org/) - that is, the JSON representation of spatial data. You can load this into R's memory as a spatial object directly using `sf::st_read()`.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)

# Store the given string in a variable
json_string <- '{ "type" : "FeatureCollection", "name" : "ADDRESS_POINT_WGS84", "features" : [ { "type" : "Feature", "geometry" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -79.539538708, 43.586921565 ] }, "properties" : { "GEO_ID" : 5729529, "LINK" : 5729516, "MAINT_STAG" : "REGULAR", "ADDRESS" : "399", "LFNAME" : "Lake Promenade", "LO_NUM" : 399, "LONUMSUF" : null, "HINUM" : null, "HINUMSUF" : null, "ARC_SIDE" : "L", "DISTANCE" : 4.15, "FCODE" : 115001, "FCODE_DES" : "Unknown", "CLASS" : "Land", "NAME" : null, "X" : 301607.151, "Y" : 4827443.931, "LONGITUDE" : -79.5395419864, "LATITUDE" : 43.5869301259, "OBJECTID" : 1491585, "MUN_NAME" : "Etobicoke", "WARD_NAME" : "Etobicoke-Lakeshore" } } ] }'

# Convert the string to a JSON object
json_data <- jsonlite::fromJSON(json_string)
my_df <- json_data$features
my_df <- my_df %>% 
  unnest_wider(col="properties")
names(my_df)
#>  [1] "type"       "geometry"   "GEO_ID"     "LINK"       "MAINT_STAG"
#>  [6] "ADDRESS"    "LFNAME"     "LO_NUM"     "LONUMSUF"   "HINUM"     
#> [11] "HINUMSUF"   "ARC_SIDE"   "DISTANCE"   "FCODE"      "FCODE_DES" 
#> [16] "CLASS"      "NAME"       "X"          "Y"          "LONGITUDE" 
#> [21] "LATITUDE"   "OBJECTID"   "MUN_NAME"   "WARD_NAME"

my_df %>% 
  filter(ADDRESS=="399") %>% 
  filter(LFNAME=="Lake Promenade")
#> # A tibble: 1 × 24
#>   type    geometry$type  GEO_ID   LINK MAINT_STAG ADDRESS LFNAME LO_NUM LONUMSUF
#>   <chr>   <chr>           <int>  <int> <chr>      <chr>   <chr>   <int> <lgl>   
#> 1 Feature Point         5729529 5.73e6 REGULAR    399     Lake …    399 NA      
#> # ℹ 16 more variables: geometry$coordinates <list>, HINUM <lgl>,
#> #   HINUMSUF <lgl>, ARC_SIDE <chr>, DISTANCE <dbl>, FCODE <int>,
#> #   FCODE_DES <chr>, CLASS <chr>, NAME <lgl>, X <dbl>, Y <dbl>,
#> #   LONGITUDE <dbl>, LATITUDE <dbl>, OBJECTID <int>, MUN_NAME <chr>,
#> #   WARD_NAME <chr>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Provided file sample is valid *GeoJSON* and spatial packages, like `sf`, can handle it directly. `sf` object is basically a dataframe with special geometry column(s), so you mostly use your standard data wrangling tools and methods to deal with attributes, be it base R or `dplyr` / Tidyverse. If you really want to, you can also use SQL queries with `sf` (only available when reading a file, so every single query reads the whole dataset from disk to memory, at least when it's stored as json). Or use `sqldf` package to use SQL on dataframes, though you'd then miss direct access to `sf` tools - https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/

```r
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

# read sample dataset, saved as sample.geojson
sample_sf <- st_read("sample.geojson", quiet = TRUE, as_tibble = TRUE)
sample_sf
#> Simple feature collection with 4 features and 22 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -79.54037 ymin: 43.58692 xmax: -79.38804 ymax: 43.68309
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 4 × 23
#>    GEO_ID     LINK MAINT_STAG ADDRESS LFNAME      LO_NUM LONUMSUF HINUM HINUMSUF
#>     <int>    <int> <chr>      <chr>   <chr>        <int> <chr>    <chr> <chr>   
#> 1 5729529  5729516 REGULAR    399     Lake Prome…    399 <NA>     <NA>  <NA>    
#> 2 9950585  9950578 REGULAR    7       Hilo Rd          7 <NA>     <NA>  <NA>    
#> 3 5729496  5729468 REGULAR    387     Lake Prome…    387 <NA>     <NA>  <NA>    
#> 4  850466 20002604 REGULAR    1       Ottawa St        1 <NA>     <NA>  <NA>    
#> # ℹ 14 more variables: ARC_SIDE <chr>, DISTANCE <dbl>, FCODE <int>,
#> #   FCODE_DES <chr>, CLASS <chr>, NAME <chr>, X <dbl>, Y <dbl>,
#> #   LONGITUDE <dbl>, LATITUDE <dbl>, OBJECTID <int>, MUN_NAME <chr>,
#> #   WARD_NAME <chr>, geometry <POINT [°]>

# filter and plot results with mapview
sample_sf %>%
  filter(ADDRESS == "7",LFNAME == "Hilo Rd") %>%
  mapview::mapview()
```

[image]

```r
# use SQL query on spatial dataset:  
st_read("sample.geojson", quiet = TRUE, as_tibble = TRUE, 
        query = "select Latitude, Longitude From ADDRESS_POINT_WGS84 Where ADDRESS = '7'")
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -79.54037 ymin: 43.58826 xmax: -79.54037 ymax: 43.58826
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   Latitude Longitude             geometry
#>      <dbl>     <dbl>          <POINT [°]>
#> 1     43.6     -79.5 (-79.54037 43.58826)

# You might want to consider more compact storage options than json 
# for larger datasets, for example GeoPackage, which is actually an SQLite file.
st_write(sample_sf, "sample.gpkg") 

# or just R rds:
readr::write_rds(sample_sf, "sample.rds")

# Though for this small sample, the resulting gpkg size exceeds json's:
list.files() %>%  file.info() %>% `[`(1)
#>                 size
#> sample.geojson  3537
#> sample.gpkg    98304
#> sample.rds      3411

# For reading, just replace the filename; sf guesses the type / driver
# from extension
sample_g <- st_read("sample.gpkg", quiet = TRUE, as_tibble = TRUE)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>